listings not cover the whole minipage area
I try to put a listing into minipage, when I set listings color to white and minipage color to grey, I found some grey color still show.
How can I make the listings cover the whole minipage area?
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\pagecolor[RGB]{128,128,128}% 
\begin{lstlisting}[
    frame=lrtb,
    numbers=left,
    language=C++,
    backgroundcolor  = \color{white},
    ]

#include <stdio.h>
// main function
int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
        if (i == 3) printf("Hello world!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}


Output:


You can adjust the belowskip:
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\pagecolor[RGB]{128,128,128}% 
\begin{lstlisting}[
    frame=lrtb,
    numbers=left,
    language=C++,
    backgroundcolor  = \color{white},
    belowskip=-2pt,
    ]

#include <stdio.h>
// main function
int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
        if (i == 3) printf("Hello world!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}%
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}



Great, but how may I know -2pt is the right value?

@lucky1928 You are artificially adding border=2pt to the page, so this needs to be removed if you don't want to see the background of the page.
